# How can I give a BorderRadius form the center in order to make this design?

Tags: flutter

I want to make smt like that,but I am unable to give a borderRadius from bottomCenter.How can I make this figure?[image]

Comment: to do that u have use CustomClipper or CustomPainter

Comment: code: https://github.com/jbjason/complex_ui/blob/main/lib/screens/meditation_ui/welcome_screen/med_wel_appbar.dart
demo pic (appBar) : https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/62088928/201593372-02ef6032-ff23-4a93-9f6c-fd9569223aae.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Didn't Get your problem exactly, but to achieve the shape in the image, you can simply do this :

```
Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
  shape: BoxShape.circle,
  color: //Put your color here,
       ),
  child: Text('text here'),
  )
```